# Regex Redirects to Remove sub folder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I’m wondering if someone can help with some Reg-Ex code development, I currently have a site which operates multiple language versions as follows
-   /en/page-url
-   /fr/page-url
-   /de/page-url
Now all of the above don’t actually load unique content so what I want to do is develop some code which will redirect all of the indivudal urls to go to the main domain so
-   /en/page-url to /page-url
Wondering if someone can help?
Kev

Comment: This is an .htaccess issue. Try searching for mod_rewrites, there is a lot of information out there about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`((\/\w{2})\/)` should capture any 2 character group of alphanumerics wedged between two `/`. If you wanted to get more specific, I suppose you could try to capture each possible 2 character abbreviation of the languages.